# Unwind segue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm currently doing the tutorial from [**Apple's Start Developing iOS Apps**](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1).

On the Tutorial: Storyboards page (link above), I'm told to make custom classes for two views. For simplicity I'll call them the Table View (has a table) and the Add View (has a text field to add items to the table).

The Table View has a button that links opens up the Add View, and the Add View has two buttons on its navigation bar: Cancel and Done.

I was told to write an empty method `unwindToList` in the .m file of the Add View:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

}
```

Then I was told to link both Cancel and Done buttons to the Exit item in the Scene Dock (see image at the bottom), and to pick the method `unwindToList`. As a result, this is what's supposed to happen, as quoted from the tutorial:

> Now, run your app. At launch, you see a table view—but there’s no data in it. You can click the Add button and navigate to [the Add View] from [the Table View]. You can click the Cancel and Done buttons to navigate back to [the Table View]."

However, when I click Cancel or Done, nothing happens at all. I'm sure both are linked.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Tutorial Image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you read the tutorial carefully you will see that the unwind method needs to be in the `UIViewController` that you are *unwinding to* - from the tutorial -

> An unwind segue is created by adding an action method to the
>   destination view controller (the view controller you want to unwind
>   to).
>
> ...
>
> Because you want to unwind back to XYZToDoListTableViewController, you need to add an action method with this format to the XYZToDoListTableViewController interface and implementation.

So, you should create your `unwindToList` method in the table view controller, not in the add view controller.

Comment: Also remember to double check the name of the method that would be called after the segue, for some reason Xcode was adding a `withSegue:` to the end of the method and that's why I wasn't able to perform it.

Comment: That sounds like a swift 3 change

Answer (score 4):

My experience has been that the unwind method in the controller being returned to must exist before you apply the segue.

Comment: yes! I was wondering why my logout unwindsegue worked sometimes but it's because I allow users to auto login and never load my login page